# Rails How To Include Module From Subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, semaphore-ci

I currently have this folder directory

1. app

   - controllers

     - project_controller.rb
     - subtasks

       - index_helper.rb

project_controller.rb

```
class ProjectController < ApplicationController
  include Subtasks::IndexHelper
```

index_helper.rb

```
module Subtasks::IndexHelper
....
```

This configuration works locally without a `require` statement. 
But when run on a CI (semaphoreci) it returns

```
ActionController::RoutingError:
        uninitialized constant Subtasks::IndexHelper
```

I've tried to use the autoload function by adding all possible sub-configurations of

```
    config.autoload_paths.push "#{config.root}/app/controllers/subtasks"
```

but this throws a different error

```
Failure/Error: include Subtasks::IndexHelper

LoadError:
Unable to autoload constant IndexHelper, expected 
/home/runner/app/controllers/subtasks/index_helper.rb to define it
```

My Question is: Is there any way to include this module without any `require`, `require_relative`, `require_dependency` clauses? This setup worked a couple months back, but it all of a sudden started failing.

Comment: do you need to manually add `subtasks` to the autoload paths, they are inside `app` so they should be loaded by rails

Comment: This isn't being autoloaded because it's not named correctly. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

Comment: Have you tried the nested format for your module? i.e. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#nesting

Comment: I've tried nesting, but it returns LoadError:
  Unable to autoload constant IndexHelper, expected /app/controllers/subtasks/index_helper.rb to define it. But it's clearly defined?